# Как в TextBox1 скопировать 1-но слово после какого-то

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

В TextBox2 есть текст такого рода:

```
Wohnort:Schweiz
Entfernung:690 km
Beruf:Ingenieurswesen
```

Как в `TextBox1` скопировать слово `Schweiz после`Wohnort`, чтобы в`TextBox1`было только слово`Schweiz`?

*Обновление*

Не понял ваш вопрос, но мне просто надо перенести текст что-то вроде такого:

```
string Town = TextBox2.Text;//TextBox2.Text Ячейка со всей информацией
Town = Town.Substring(Town.IndexOf("Wohnort:"));// Нужные мне данные находяться после этого слова.
Town = Town.Remove(Town.IndexOf("Entfernung:"));// Это слово я поставил для того чтобы мне в нужную ячейку не закидывал всё что после..
Town = Town.Replace("Wohnort:", ""); //Удаляю Начальное слово чтобы тоже не попадало в нужную мне ячейку
TextBox1.Text = (Town);
```

но иногда может отсутствовать слово "Entfernung:" и быть Каким-то другим. Так что надо как-то по другому.

У меня всё это работает, я показал каким образом,  Но я Уверен что это всё можно написать проще в три строки, что-то вроде:

```
string Town = TextBox2.Text; 
Town.Substring(Town.IndexOf("Wohnort:"));
Town = Town.ХЗ(Town.Хз("[^ ]Мать его Одно Слово до пробела"))
```

Есть какие-то мысли?

### Ответ:

Вы писали, что получаете текст в TextBox2 с помощью регулярных выражений, добавьте какой то символ в конец каждого найденного результата, скажем "_" 
у вас получится выражение такого рода :

```
Wohnort:Schweiz__
Entfernung:690 km__
Beruf:Ingenieurswesen__
```

А теперь можете провернуть ваше действие таким образом

---

```
string Town = TextBox2.Text;
Town = Town.Substring(Town.IndexOf("Wohnort:"));
Town = Town.Replace("Wohnort:", "");
TextBox1.Text = Town.Remove(Town.IndexOf("_"));
```

Теперь не важно будет ли ваше второе слово из

```
Town = Town.Remove(Town.IndexOf("Entfernung:"));
```

или какое то другое у вас есть символ от которого отталкиваться.

а вот таким образом:

```
if (userinformbox.Text.Contains("Wohnort:"))
{
  string Town = TextBox2.Text;;
  Town = Town.Substring(Town.IndexOf("Wohnort:"));
  Town = Town.Replace("Wohnort:", "");
  TextBox1.Text; = Town.Remove(Town.IndexOf("_"));
}
```

Вам даже не важно будет ли нужная позиция вообще, если не будет, перейдёт к следующему if
Если есть вопросы пишите, чем могу помогу.
    ----------

```
ВОТ ТАК ВОТ ("Вашу " + "Cами дальше додумывайте кого");
------------------------
```

Comment: Вы уверены, что название и само существование контрола неизвестного фреймворка с именем `TextBox1` имеет отношение к сути дела?

Comment: Обновил вопрос

Comment: >Не понял ваш вопрос

вопрос в том,какая вообще разница, как называется ваш текстбокс? Будь это TextBox1, TextBox2 или как-то еще, какое это отношение имеет к самой задаче?

Comment: Да не имеет воопще никакой разницы, просто к примеру написал TextBox1

Comment: Хорошо. тогда конкретно опишите, что и по каким правилам вам нужно скопировать. Пока что ваш вопрос выглядит очень туманным: "надо скопировать одно слово  после другого слова, которого может и не быть или вместо него может быть что-то другое". По каким критериям программа должна понять, что и откуда копировать?

Comment: Ок Постараюсь расписать, секунду

Comment: Постараюсь, 
Я в TextBox2 Заливаю определённую информаци через Регулярные выражения,
резулят такого рода:
Wohnort:Schweiz
Entfernung:690 km
Beruf:Ingenieurswesen

Далее мне надо сделать так чтобы в TextBox1 в если есть слово Wohnort: Скопировалось то что после него

в TextBox3 если есть слово Entfernung: Скопировалось то что после него
только одно слово а не ВСЁ что после.

Comment: @Rubenovich: Выкиньте из вопроса текстбокс, а? Если ваша проблема в том, как достать текст из текстбокса и положить его в другой, мы говорим не на том уровне.

Answer (score 2):

C оегулярным выражением не подскажу, поскольку не силен в них, однако это можно провернуть "обычным" способом. Если я правильно понял ваше условие, то вам нужно что-то такое:

```
const string source = "Wohnort:Schweiz Entfernung:690 km Beruf:Ingenieurswesen";
const string firstWord = "Wohnort";
const string secdondWord = "Entfernung";

string res = "";
if(source.Contains(firstWord))
{
    int pos = source.IndexOf(firstWord);
    res = pos != -1 ?  source.Substring(pos + firstWord.Length) : "";            
}
else
{
    var dividers = new[] { ':', ',', ' ', '.' };
    if (source.IndexOf(secdondWord) != -1)
    {
        int firstPos = source.IndexOf(secdondWord) + secdondWord.Length + 1;
        string substr = source.Substring(firstPos);
        var positions = dividers.Select(x => substr.IndexOf(x))                                       
                                .Where(x => x != -1);
        res = positions.Any() ? source.Substring(firstPos, positions.Min()) : "";
    }
    else
        res = "";
}
Console.WriteLine(res);
```

Comment: У меня всё в WinForms, извините но я не могу воплотить таким образом, у меня не получаеться задать 
вместе "Wohnort:Schweiz Entfernung:690 km Beruf:Ingenieurswesen"; нужный мне TextBox

Comment: Вы не можете вместо строки под названием source подставить строку TextBox1.Text? В таком случае вам имеет смысл ознакомиться с основами языка

Comment: Так Люди вы мне всё усложняете, У меня всё это работает, я показал каким образом,  Но я Уверен что это всё можно написать проще в три строки, что-то вроде:
string Town = TextBox2.Text;
Town = Town.Substring(Town.IndexOf("Wohnort:"));
Town = Town.ХЗ(Town.Хз("[^ ]Мать его Слово до пробела"))
Есть какието мысли?

Comment: @Rubenovich: Вы должны уметь записать строку в текстбокс и считать её оттуда. Если не умеете — не позорьтесь, идите читать документацию и приходите потом.

Остальное и самое сложное — преобразование строки — вам показали в ответе.

И да, то, что вам надо, не делается одним магическим вызовом.

Comment: Не ну ты посмотри на него! Я Щас принцепиально Сделаю то что задумал, А Потом закину вариант Сюда и тогда скажу кому что надо учить.АААААААА!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Читайте обновлённый вопрос.